# How to find unique key with desire array value?

Tags: javascript

I want to get unique `p` which `c` values contain all `desire_c` value !

So here `object's` **p:1** has c value like 1,2,3 . That is match desire_c array value , **so I want to get**

**`{p:1}` as final result !**

Here I am looping in using *for loop* :(

```js
var object = [{p:1,c:1},{p:1,c:2},{p:1,c:3},{p:2,c:1},{p:3,c:3}];
var desire_c = [1,2,3];

var helper = {};
for(var o in object) {
  var current = object[o];
  if(typeof helper[current.p] != 'object') {
     helper[current.p] = {};     
  }
  helper[current.p][current.c] = null;  
}

for(var c of helper) {
   for(var d in desire_c) {
     c[desire_c[d]]
   }
}
```

Comment: `c[desire_c[d]]` what should that do? And dont use `for..in` to iterate Arrays!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how two arrays should match? For example, does `[3,1,2]` match `[1,2,3]`? Or `[1,1,2,3,3]` and `[1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this auxiliary function to find the unique value:

```
function findKey(objects, desire){
    const map = {}; // Creates a new object to map all keys to all their values, instead of having an array of objects
    objects.forEach(obj => {
        map[obj.p] = map[obj.p] || []; // Ensures the key has an array of values before pushing a new value
        map[obj.p].push(obj.c);
    });

    return Object.keys(map).find(key => desire.every(des => map[key].includes(des))); // Tries to find a key that contains all desired values
}
```

Then, just call it like that:

```
findKey(object, desire_c); // Returns 1 for your example
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a map for `p` and a set for each `c` value and check then if all wanted values are in a set.

```js
var object = [{ p: 1, c: 1 }, { p: 1, c: 2 }, { p: 1, c: 3 }, { p: 2, c: 1 }, { p: 3, c: 3 }],
    desire_c = [1, 2, 3],
    map = new Map,
    result;

object.forEach(({ p, c }) => map.has(p) ? map.get(p).add(c) : map.set(p, new Set([c])));

result = [...map.keys()].filter(p => desire_c.every(c => map.get(p).has(c)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `x.every(set.has(x))` doesn't mean the sets are equal... Try adding `{p:1, c:99}` to `object`.

Comment: @georg, op has not stated, if the result should contain exactly the values or just all, even if the objects contain dupes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
 var desire_c = [1,2,3];
 var data=[{p:1,c:1},{p:1,c:2},{p:1,c:3},{p:2,c:1},{p:3,c:3}];;
 var helper = {},element = "p";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!helper[data[i][element]])
        helper[data[i][element]] = [];
    helper[data[i][element]].push(data[i]["c"]);
};

for (key in helper) {
    if (helper.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (helper[key].length){
            var arr=helper[key];
            if(JSON.stringify(arr)==JSON.stringify(desire_c))
             {

                 console.log({"p":key});
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 const hash = {};

 for(const {p, c} of object){
  if(!hash[p]){
   hash[p] = desire_c;
  }
  hash[p] = hash[p].filter(n => n !== c);
 }

 const result = [];
 for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(hash))
   if(!val.length) result.push(key);
```

This just goes over every `p` and `c` in the array, and removes `c` from the array stored inside the hashtable under `p`. This array is initialized to your wanted array, so if all elements are removed from it (`!val.length`) the corresponding key is the one we are looking for.

Comment: Your answer is work ! But actually I don't understand your working code , if you have time would you like to explain me more detail !!!